# How to hilight pair brackets in Scintilla.net?

Tags: c#, scintilla

How to hilight pair brackets ( "{" and "}" ) in Scintilla.net?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the IsBraceMatching property of your ScintillaNet control to true and it will highlight (), [] and {}.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get highlighting only in comments regions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of ScintillaNet you are using but this should help:

https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/wiki/Brace-Matching

With highlight to:

```
int lastCaretPos = 0;

private void scintilla_UpdateUI(object sender, UpdateUIEventArgs e)
{
    // Has the caret changed position?
    var caretPos = scintilla.CurrentPosition;
    if (lastCaretPos != caretPos)
    {
        lastCaretPos = caretPos;
        var bracePos1 = -1;
        var bracePos2 = -1;

        // Is there a brace to the left or right?
        if (caretPos > 0 && IsBrace(scintilla.GetCharAt(caretPos - 1)))
            bracePos1 = (caretPos - 1);
        else if (IsBrace(scintilla.GetCharAt(caretPos)))
            bracePos1 = caretPos;

        if (bracePos1 >= 0)
        {
            // Find the matching brace
            bracePos2 = scintilla.BraceMatch(bracePos1);
            if (bracePos2 == Scintilla.InvalidPosition)
                scintilla.BraceBadLight(bracePos1);
            else
                scintilla.BraceHighlight(bracePos1, bracePos2);
        }
        else
        {
            // Turn off brace matching
            scintilla.BraceHighlight(Scintilla.InvalidPosition, Scintilla.InvalidPosition);
        }
    }
}

private static bool IsBrace(int c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case '(':
        case ')':
        case '[':
        case ']':
        case '{':
        case '}':
        case '<':
        case '>':
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```